# Image Tracking on a curved surface in ARCore?

Tags: vuforia, arcore

I'm looking to track images on a curved surface. I have seen the Vuforia image tracking stuff (Vuforia cylinder target), and was wondering if we could produce a similar effect in ARCore, possibly with multiple images in a database? Anyone with any experience in this area, or even any views or advice would be a big help.

Comment: Vuforia has many tracking features. Do you mean image targets when you say tracking? Can you elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve. How did you achieve tracking curved surface on Vuforia?

Comment: Vuforia can have cylinder tracking objects. So an image wrapped around a cylinder.

Comment: I do not think you can track rolled augmented images using ARCore. In fact is a feature request for [ARCore](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/494)

Comment: I thought that might be the case, is there anyway of knowing if they are likely to implement this in the near(12 months) future?

Comment: Well i would not count on that. Why don't you want to use Vuforia instead?

Comment: We need to be able to update Image Databases on the fly. The system for ARCore gives us the best options for that. Its unfortunate that Vuforia, doesn't give the best options in that area but does for other parts of image tracking.

Comment: The only thing i can think of is using more than one images for per cylinder and using [auto focus]. Maybe you can test this with different markers and different amount of markers in order to try to find out how many markers you have to use for optimal tracking.

Comment: Way ahead on that one. Depending on the width of the cylinder, there is a real variance in how warped each image becomes, the same above and below. A picture taken from below or above the object will have a very different collection of point relationships between features, even on the same axis.

Comment: I understand but what i am suggesting is different. I am thinking of using multiple small markers on a cylinder. They will be smaller but you might be able to track them using auto focus from ARCore. I have not tested it but i am thinking it can work. The resulting geometry is up to you to apply in your code depending on how you applied markers on top of cylinder.